# Rails omniauth facebook no_authorization_code error on cancel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am using `ng token auth` and `devise token auth`. Wen i login to facebook the process works well, but when i click on the cancel button i am getting this error:

```
Started GET "/api/auth/facebook/callback?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&state=e3189ef7413776747cfec392570cce4a42e7bd8504d5245b" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-04 13:23:53 +0200
I, [2016-01-04T13:23:53.319820 #72138]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2016-01-04T13:23:53.322147 #72138] ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! no_authorization_code: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::NoAuthorizationCodeError, must pass either a `code` (via URL or by an `fbsr_XXX` signed request cookie)

AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'failure' could not be found for Api::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

What is the problem with the cancel button?

Comment: Can you please share your code, how you are handling access_denied callback ?

Comment: I did not add something special, the gem don't care to this?